# MySQLi - Trouble running query

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

Here is my code:

```
<?php

require "../include/functions.php";

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 

ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase();

$Cat = addslashes($_POST["Category"]);

$v = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id`=$Cat");
$vrowi = mysql_fetch_array($v);

$url = $conn->real_escape_string($vrowi['Link']);   


if($Cat!=""){
$conn->query("DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `Category`='$Cat'");
```

Here is the `ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase();` function which is in `functions.php`:

```
$CURRENTPATH = dirname(__FILE__);

require_once("$CURRENTPATH/config.php");


function ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase() {

     global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database, $HTTP_SERVER_VARS;

    $conn=mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }


    $conn->set_charset("utf8");

}
```

In config file i have setted `$dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database,` variables correctly.

When i try to run these queries i get this error:

```
    <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: conn in <b>/var/www/html/sportsector.bg/admin/fetch_category_products
.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in <b>/var/www/html/sportsector
.bg/admin/fetch_category_products.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
```

Where is my mistake and how can i fix it?

**Second question:**
Until now i used `mysql_query` as extension for PHP to connect with `MySQL` databases. What do you think. What will be easier for me to use `mysqli` or `pdo` as new extension for connecting `MySQL` databases. Which one is closer to the old one `mysql_query`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `$conn` exists only in a scope of function `ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase`.

Comment: I advise you to read mysqli manual on php site and feel the difference between `object-oriented` and `procedural` approach of mysqli. After that you will have less questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your $conn object is never declared, at least not in the code you're showing. You assume $conn is a global object instantiated with mysqli_connect(). Well, it is not. If you want to use it as an object, invoke the constructor with the new keyword.

$conn= **new** mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database);

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't confuse yourself with *object oriented* and *procedural style* of writing query. Some where using **object oriented style** and Some where using **procedural style**.

I have updated your code in both way. Choose one. And, Go Ahead. Then, come with error. Ok.

**Object Oriented.**

```
<?php

require "../include/functions.php";

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase();

$Cat = addslashes($_POST["Category"]);
$v = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id`=$Cat");
$vrowi = $v->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$url = $conn->real_escape_string($vrowi['Link']);   

if($Cat!=""){
$conn->query("DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `Category`='$Cat'");

ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase(); function which is in functions.php:

$CURRENTPATH = dirname(__FILE__);
require_once("$CURRENTPATH/config.php");

function ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase() {
    global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database, $HTTP_SERVER_VARS;
    $conn=new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $conn->set_charset("utf8");
}
?>
```

**Procedural Style**

```
<?php

require "../include/functions.php";

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase();

$Cat = addslashes($_POST["Category"]);
$v =  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id`=$Cat");
$vrowi = mysqli_fetch_array($v, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$url = $conn->real_escape_string($vrowi['Link']);

if($Cat!=""){
 mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `Category`='$Cat'");
ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase(); function which is in functions.php:
$CURRENTPATH = dirname(__FILE__);
require_once("$CURRENTPATH/config.php");

function ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase() {

    global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database, $HTTP_SERVER_VARS;

    $conn=mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $conn->set_charset("utf8");
}
?>
```

Comment: From `$mysqli->real_escape_string($vrowi['Link']);` Where you define `$mysqli` ?

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to use this line:

```
$url = $conn->real_escape_string($vrowi['Link']);
```

then

```
$vrowi = mysql_fetch_array($v);
```

should be

```
$vrowi = mysqli_fetch_assoc($v);
```

Comment: Do you even understand that as OP uses `mysqli` (with `i`) then `mysql_` functions will not work?